# c# linq Query on datatable groupby having count

Tags: linq, group-by, datatable, having

I have a datatable and I need to perform the following query on it (sql):

```
SELECT C1, C2, C3, count(*)
FROM MyTable
group by C1, C2, C3
having COUNT (*) > 1
```

Can you point me to some code, in order to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: This `DataTable`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-7.0
If so, that's an in-memory collection. So maybe you should change the query that filled the `DataTable` instead of modifying it afterwards.

Comment: I don't fill the datatable with a query, it comes from parsing an excel file

Comment: What types are C1, C2 and C3, strings?

Comment: yes they happen to be strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple LINQ query with `GroupBy`:

```
var query = table.AsEnumerable()
   .GroupBy(r => (C1:r.Field<string>("C1"), C2:r.Field<string>("C2"), C3:r.Field<string>("C3")))
   .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
   .Select(g => (g.Key.C1, g.Key.C2, g.Key.C3, Count: g.Count()));
```

If you want to add it to a new `DataTable`:

```
DataTable resultTable = new();
resultTable.Columns.Add("C1");
resultTable.Columns.Add("C2");
resultTable.Columns.Add("C3");
resultTable.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(int));

foreach(var x in query)
{
    resultTable.Rows.Add(x.C1, x.C2, x.C3, x.Count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how do i get a new datatable from this linq query?

Comment: No it contains other columns as well

Comment: I need only these 3 columns plus the count column